# Bootstrap 5, col-sm-6 overwrites col-md

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

In Bootstrap 5, I want columns to have size evenly in a row. But on small screens I want them to be exactly size 6. In this example, columns must be size 3 for screens that bigger than md. But in this case, they become size 6 whatever screen size is. If I remove col-sm-6, they work properly. I am new to Bootstrap as you can see, it seems like I didn't understand something.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md col-sm-6">
      <div class="card text-white bg-success mb-3 mx-auto" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header text-center">1111111</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text text-center">1111111</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md col-sm-6">
      <div class="card text-white bg-success mb-3 mx-auto" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header text-center">222222</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text text-center">2222222</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md col-sm-6">
      <div class="card text-white bg-success mb-3 mx-auto" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header text-center">33333333</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text text-center">3333333</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md col-sm-6">
      <div class="card text-white bg-success mb-3 mx-auto" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header text-center">444444444</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text text-center">444444444</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ5qn.png)

Comment: To make people help you, they will need css file with definition of your classes as well

Comment: @DimaMalko I thought it was a logical error. I edited the post

Comment: I mean, i see you defined "col-sm-6" so i dont undestand why it should not be 6 as you described that you expect. Maybe im not falimiliar with bootstrap 5 as well. hopefully someone will understand your question better than i do

Comment: It should be 6 for small screens. For bigger screens, I want them to be adjusted evenly. But in this case, they don't. They always become 6. I am not familiar either, just trying to learn

Comment: They work as expected: https://codeply.com/p/SHf7rY4NS7

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining the columns in order? Bootstrap breakpoints can be a bit tricky.

So `col-md col-sm-6;` so `col-12` means that when the screen is less than 576px, then `col-sm-6` means that when the screen is above 576px to make the columns 6.

Here is the breakpoint list: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/breakpoints/